# Out of Memory on Windows Mobile 5

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

My application is running out of memory.  It runs on an MC70.

It happens when I pull a lot of data down from a Web Service.  I know I have a lot of data in memory, but I am wondering if there are any tricks of the trade when dealing with this kind of thing.

Here is my scenario, I have a soap service that gets activity data, including images (stored in blobs on the server).  Sometimes this is a lot of data and sometimes it is very little.

The out of memory exception happens when it is a ton of data.

Are there any tricks to dealing with out of memory exceptions with Windows Mobile?

Note: I am in the process of moving this app to Windows Mobile 6.5 and the MC75.  If there is a feature of 6.5 that could help with this then that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to have all data in memory at once?

A solution used by html is to download all data except images, but including a reference to each blob to be downloaded after parsing the html. Users usually don't mind waiting for an image to load if it speeds up the initial load, and if the text is already visible.

Comment: I like this, I will give it further thought and see if it will work.